# AttributeError: type object 'Config' has no attribute 'resize'

Tags: python, data-generation

```
def preprocessing(img,label):

    img = cv2.resize(img,(Config.resize,Config.resize))
    img = img/255
    label = np_utils.to_categorical(label, Config.num_classes)
```

When I want to resize the image, it keep show the error on type object 'Config' has no attribute 'resize'. Do anyone one know what happen?

Comment: Can you check the type of the Config object?

Comment: Sorry because I dont know how to check...When I run the below coding, this error comes out...

train_datagen = data_generator(samples,batch_size=8)

x,y = next(train_datagen)
print ('x_shape: ', x.shape)
print ('labels shape: ', y.shape)
print ('labels: ', y)